# Shape my raw text data to columns using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on building a flat file using pandas which consists of properties of items like Age ,Gender , Behavior etc.
All I have is one flat file which consists of a unique key for each item and a text column in which there list of properties which does not specify which property they are speaking about , will be similar to the below table

[image]

Then the properties are something like this in a single file . It says about the properties of item whether it can be consumed by Male , Female and Age etc

[image]

The text which is in table1 and table2

I am looking to make the final data frame as below.

[image]

Can anyone let me know easy way to do this.

Thankyou in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by creating a master dictionary to lookup the values and creating the dataframe.

Here are the steps:

1. The flatfile with properties and sub-categories. Create a master lookup dictionary with sub-category as key and property as value. This allows us to look up the sub-category and find the property value.
2. Read each row in the file. Then split them on commas. Then take each value and lookup the master lookup dictionary we created in step 1.
3. Make sure we capture the Index for each row (ItemA, ItemB).
4. Create a data dictionary with the index key and the properties.
5. Create a dataframe using the data dictionary. Then transpose to get the keys as Index.

Here's the code.

```
master_dict = {'<35':'Age','>35':'Age','M':'Gender','F':'Gender','White':'BehaviorA','Black':'BehaviorA',
               'Red':'BehaviorA','Big':'BehaviorB','Small':'BehaviorB','Medium':'BehaviorC'}
               
file_data = '''\
Index,Properties
ItemA,F,Red,Small,Medium,<35
ItemB,>35,Black,Big,M'''

#initialize the pandas dataframe dictionary
data_dict = {}

#iterate through each row in the file
for i, line in enumerate(file_data.split('\n')):
    #ignore header row (i == 0)
    if i == 0:continue

    #remove \n and leading spaces. split on comma
    prop = line.strip().split(',')

    #initialize dict for each item
    d = {}
    for ix, p in enumerate(prop):
        #capture index values (ItemA, ItemB)
        if ix == 0: key = p;continue

        #for all others, get the column header and value
        #column header is mapped to the value in the master dictionary; use that
        else: d[master_dict[p]]=p

    #create a row with the index value
    data_dict[key] = d

#once all the rows have been added to the data dictionary, its ready for us to create a dataframe
import pandas as pd
#create a dataframe with the data dictionary. transpose will ensure keys are set as index
df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict).T

print (df)
```

The output of this will be:

```
      Gender BehaviorA BehaviorB BehaviorC  Age
ItemA      F       Red     Small    Medium  <35
ItemB      M     Black       Big       NaN  >35
```